# Как в playbook ansible выполнить одну роль локально, а другую на удаленной машине?

Tags: ansible

Как в playbook ansible выполнить одну роль локально, а другую на удаленной машине? 
Playbook должен выполнить некие действия сначала на сервере, откуда запускается, а потом на удаленных машинах

Comment: Укажите, что конкретно нужно выполнить.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать модуль **deligate_to** с указанием локального хоста 127.0.0.1.

```
---

- hosts: webservers
  serial: 5

  tasks:

  - name: take out of load balancer pool
    command: /usr/bin/take_out_of_pool {{ inventory_hostname }}
    delegate_to: 127.0.0.1

  - name: actual steps would go here
    yum:
      name: acme-web-stack
      state: latest

  - name: add back to load balancer pool
    command: /usr/bin/add_back_to_pool {{ inventory_hostname }}
    delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
```

**Ссылки**

- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation

Comment: Ещё есть `local_action`.